# Passing Environment variable to Webpack 2 after build

Tags: docker, environment-variables, webpack-2

I have a problem that requires me to reference environment variables in Webpack 2. For reference, I've described the context of the issue below:

- We are using vue-cli Webpack 2 boilerplate
- We are running 2 different builds (based on the boilerplate)

  - npm run dev (local)
  - npm run build (integration, uat, production tiers)
- We have API and Server urls that change depending on integration/uat/production tier
- Our CI/CD Pipeline works as follows

  - Run Travis script to build UI, running *npm run build* command, on Integration tier
  - On success, build and deploy a Docker container on Integration tier
  - The same Docker container is then pushed to UAT and Production tiers in order
- We use Apache as our Web Server

The problem is, Webpack builds the site. Docker container is then built, and deployed on multiple tiers in order. Therefore Webpack has no way of knowing/accessing some value during the build, that tells it which SERVER and API urls to use (as they are different for Integration, UAT, and Production), because the same Docker container is used on the 3 tiers mentioned above.

My question
- Is there a way to change/pass environment variables and set the correct urls post-Webpack build?
- If not, what is the best approach to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: its open issue 
https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/1527

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/578